# How to evaluate a sum in excel to return 0 if the sum of two values is >0 (for my data I do not care about Positive values)

Tags: excel

I am summing loads for member design and have the correct values for downforce.  However, when I use my formulas for uplift (-) if there is no uplift it returns a positive value which is objectively correct however it is not needed for my purposes.  I only need negative values for uplift.

I've tried
sumif(Range,SUM(Range)<0,Sum Range)
sumif(Range,"<0")... this just returns the only negative value which is not what I need

basically, i still need to sum the data but if it returns a positive it should return zero, and if it returns a negative keep the value

Ex.)

2+3 should = 0
3-9 should = -6

Answer (score 2):

You can use MIN to not allow the value to become greater than `0`

```
=MIN(SUM(A1,A2),0)
```

This will make any positive number `0` because `0` is lower than any positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
=IF(SUM(J87+K87)>0,0,J87+K87)
```

[image]

[image]